# Foq intercept generic method with unknown type

Tags: f#, foq

Given

```
public interface IFoo { void F<T>(int i, T arg); }

public class Sut
{
    private struct My { public object o; }
    private class My2 { public int i; }
    
    public void M(IFoo foo)
    {
        foo.F(2, new My { o = DateTime.UtcNow });
        foo.F(2, new My2 { i = int.MaxValue });
    }
}
```

I want to intercept `IFoo`:

```
open NUnit.Framework
open Foq

MockMode.Default <- MockMode.Strict

[<Test>]
let ``Te2st`` () =
    let foo =
        Mock<IFoo>()
            // .SetupByName("F").Returns(()) // this one works but, no way to verify args

            // doesn't call Calls callback
            .SetupMethod(fun x -> <@ x.F @>)

            // doesn't call Calls callback
            // .Setup(fun x -> <@ x.F(2, any()) @>)

            // always throws InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
            //    at Mock.IFoo3b881ed2-a550-4e58-b969-37110e0278e9.F[T](Int32, T)
            .Calls<_>(fun x -> printfn $"{x}")

            // type punning: I don't want be that UNSAFE and doesn't work for multiple 'T (InvalidProgramException)
            // .Calls<int * struct {| i: object |}>(fun x -> printfn $"{x}")

            .Create()

    Sut().M(foo)
```

---

Foq last updated 5 years ago and @ptrelford (it's maintainer) is not active any more. What does people use nowadays?